# How to run node.js file from azure-pipeline.yml?

Tags: node.js, bash, azure, azure-devops

I have an Azure ci/cd pipeline set up running scripts among other things from the azure-pipelines.yml file. I am trying to run the following script defined in my package.json

```
 - script: | 
    npm run ui-test
  displayName: 'run ui-test'
```

I get the error:

> [command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc
>   /home/vsts/work/_temp/df3bb798-9942-4d18-ae5a-0ada6afaa797.sh
>       npm ERR! missing script: ui-test

Do I need to define the script somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

One does not need to define the script anywhere else. Npm will reference the current package.json. In this instance, a pervious azure step was checking out different branch with different package.json.

Comment: Very appreciate this solution shared here ! You can accept this answer thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works:-)